# adjective order: clean, treated water or treated, clean water?

Tags: adjective-order

I'd like to know which order of adjectives is correct in the following sentence.
If both are OK, what's the difference?

> Finally, the wastewater flows into the last tanks, where the chemical chlorine is added to kill
> the remaining bacteria. After the bacteria are destroyed, the chlorine is eliminated from the water, and the
> **treated clean** water is discharged into a river or the ocean.

Comment: You might find the accepted answer to this ELU question useful: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order

Comment: Right, so first, what kind of water is it? Answer: it is **treated water**. OK: Is **treated water** clean? Answer: Yes, it is.. OK, so now what you have is: **clean, treated water**.  However, in a description, you can say here "the treated, clean water", too. It depends on what you want to emphasize. Both are fine.

Answer (score 1):

From the context of the sample paragraph, 'treated' and 'clean' are equal adjectives.  Either order of their appearance is hence fine.  A comma, however, is needed between them.

'After the bacteria are destroyed, the chlorine is eliminated from the water, and the treated, clean water is discharged into a river or the ocean.'

Edit to answer @Smart Humanism's comments

Coordinate adjectives should be separated with commas.

Exceptions are rare.  I found only one mention, in [Thoughtco](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-coordinate-adjectives-1689739), which states Amy Einsohn's observation that "[t]he convention of placing a comma between coordinate adjectives seems to be fading", for various reasons.

All other sites I have checked say commas should be used.

Comment: Is the comma you added a must or a choice of style?

Answer (score -1):

As Micah has said English does have some conventions for [ordering of adjectives](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/%E2%80%A6).

In this case, to my ears, both orders do seem valid, the choice could be on the basis of the emphasis of the sentence. Here I think the focus is that

> clean water is discharged

so I think that the author has chosen correctly in grouping clean and water.